# Default applications for LXSession in Raspbian Stretch

Tags: raspbian-stretch, lxsession

In the Jessie release of Raspbian there is a "Default applications for LXSession" that could be enabled in the Preferences tab of the main menu. It allowed (among other things) the user to specify a program or script to run automatically at boot. After upgrading to Raspbian "Stretch" I cannot find it. Does anyone know how to enable its functionality in Stretch?

Answer (score 1):

Raspbian Jessie had Default Applications for LXsession installed by default, but Stretch and beyond do not.

To install:

```
sudo apt -y install lxsession-default-apps
```

When finished, it should display automatically in the menu. If not try rebooting and making sure it is visible in the menu editor.

Answer (score 0):

Right-Click on a Panel
select Panel Settings
this opens Panel Preferences dialog
choose the Advanced tab
Set Preferred Applications
File Manager: {the drop down should allow you to select File Manager}

I had the same problem.
I don't know why it wasn't selected by default.

Comment: OP is asking how to access Default Applications for LXsession, but you just explained how to set lxpanel's default file manager.